# Keeping the dependent drop down list selected after validation in yii

Tags: php, html, yii

So here is what i am doing, i have created a dependent drop down in a form and i am validating it on my controller :

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Management;

        if(isset($_POST['Management']))
        {
            if($_POST['Management']['company_id']==''){
                //error please select a company
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('company_error',"Please select a company.");
                $this->redirect(array('create'));
            }else{
                if($_POST['Management']['site_id']==''){
                    //error please select a site
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('site_error',"Please select a site.");
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('cid',$_POST['Management']['company_id']);
                    $this->redirect(array('create'));
                }else{
                    //save
                    $model->attributes=$_POST['Management'];
                    if($model->save())
                        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
                }
            }

        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,'update'=>''
        ));
    }
```

and i am passing the company id to my form view, and i want to keep the previous drop down selected if the validation fails. this is what my dropdown looks like :

```
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'company_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'company_id', $company, /*array('options'=>array($cid=>array('selected'=>true))),*/
                array(
                        'ajax' => array(
                                'type'=>'POST',
                                'url'=>CController::createUrl('Management/dropDownSite'),
                                'update'=>'#SectorManagement_site_id',
                                'data'=>array('CompanyId'=>'js:this.value'),
                ))); 
        ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'company_id'); ?>
    </div>
```

Now when i uncomment the code :

```
array('options'=>array($cid=>array('selected'=>true))),
```

from the above drop down it shows the pre-selected value but then the dependent drop down does not work..any idea how should i solve this. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I do not know the yii framework, but have you tried moving this `array('options'=>array($cid=>array('selected'=>true))),` after the `ajax` array?

Comment: yep, did that too, but with no luck :(

Comment: what is `$cid`? where do you get this value from?

Comment: That contains the `company id` (`$_POST['Management']['company_id']`), which i am sending to the view if the validation fails..to get a pre-selected dropdown

Comment: Check out this [post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/11748-dropdownlist-selected-option/page__view__findpost__p__57551), is it possible then that `$cid` is not getting a value? Perhaps try to `echo vardump($cid);`.

Comment: no i checked it `$cid` is getting the value and the drop down gets the pre selected value if i un-comment the code as i have mentioned above, but then my dependant drop down stops working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out finally, this is how it worked for me:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Management;

        if(isset($_POST['Management']))
        {
            if($_POST['Management']['company_id']==''){
                //error please select a company
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('company_error',"Please select a company.");
                $this->redirect(array('create'));
            }else{
                if($_POST['Management']['site_id']==''){
                    //error please select a site
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('site_error',"Please select a site.");
                    $model->company_id = $_POST['Management']['company_id'];
                    $this->render('create',array(
                    'model'=>$model,
                    'update'=>'',
                ));
                exit;
                }else{
                    //save
                    $model->attributes=$_POST['Management'];
                    if($model->save())
                        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
                }
            }

        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,'update'=>''
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at this the wrong way. If your validation fails, you redirect, while you are already on the page you are redirecting too.

I am not a 100% sure but what I think you are looking for in your action is

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Management;

    if (isset($_POST['Management'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Management'];

        if ($_POST['Management']['company_id'] == '') {
            //error please select a company
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('company_error', "Please select a company.");
        } elseif ($_POST['Management']['site_id'] == '') {
            //error please select a site
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('site_error', "Please select a site.");
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('cid', $_POST['Management']['company_id']);
        } elseif ($model->save()) {
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
        }
    }

    $this->render(
        'create',
        array(
            'model' => $model,
            'update' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

Your view can probably stay how it is.

To improve this even further you should handle validation in your model as in :

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('company_id, site_id', 'required'),
    );
}
```

and then all you would need to do in your action is :

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Management;

    if (isset($_POST['Management'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Management'];
        if ($model->validate() && $model->save()) {
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
        }
    }

    $this->render(
        'create',
        array(
            'model' => $model,
            'update' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: if you still want to use the flash msg you could add foreach($model->getErrors() as `$attribute=>$error) { Yii::app()->user->setFlash('ManagementError', $error); }` after the validation condition in the controller

Comment: it is't working is nothing, is something that should never be used in problem solving, maybe it does something but not what you expected it to do, maybe you get an error that could help us fix the problem, its not because my keyboard isn't plugged in, it isn't working. Please elaborate.